# How to compare dates from two different datasets in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have 2 datasets and I need to somehow get a date column from  dataset 1 to be compared to another date column in dataset 2.

df1

```
REQUEST_ID      NAME       CREATED_DATE      PRIOR_DATE      STATUS 
100             ADAM        1/24/2022        10/24/2021     Approved
101             GRACE       4/12/2022        1/12/2022      Approved
102             BLAKE D.    9/21/2022        6/21/2022      Pending 
103             FRANK       5/18/2022        2/18/2022      Approved
```

df2

```
  ID      Name      Start_Date       End_Date       Team 
10000    Michael    11/23/2021       1/23/2022      Sales 
10000    Michael    1/23/2022        5/2/2022       Sales 
10001    Adam       9/24/2021        12/22/2021     Tech 
10001    Adam       12/22/2021       4/5/2022       HR 
10001    Adam       4/5/2022         9/21/2022      HR 
10002    Grace      7/24/2021        12/31/2021     Finance
10002    Grace      12/31/2021       3/5/2022       Finance
10002    Grace      3/5/2022         9/23/2022      Tech 
.
.
.
10025    Blake      11/22/2021       3/12/2022      Sales 
10025    Blake      3/12/2022        6/30/2022      Sales
10025    Blake      6/30/2022        9/12/2022      Sales
```

df2 continues down in numeric order until Blake, so the names above in df1 are in df2. I need to find what `ID` from df2 has a `Start_Date` that falls in range of the `CREATED_DATE` and `PRIOR_DATE` and what team do they align with at time. Only issue is that not all names match or have same formatting so merging can't be  done correctly. I have never done anything like this before so I am kind of lost on how to proceed. Below is a desired look.

Desired Output

```
 ID      Name     Start_Date     End_Date     Status      Team 
10000   Michael   11/23/2021     1/23/2022    Approved    Sales
10000   Michael   1/23/2022      5/2/2022     Approved    Sales 
10001   Adam      9/24/2022      12/22/2021   Approved    HR
10001   Adam      12/22/2021     4/5/2022     Approved    Finance
10002   Grace     3/5/2022       9/23/2022    Approved    Tech 
.
.
.
10025   Blake     6/30/2022      9/12/2022    Pending     Sales
```

If anyone knows a way to do it could really use the help. Thank you

Comment: Is this homework?  I feel like I've seen this problem before.  You'll need to have some kind of rule to decide if the names match.  There's no `.is_close_to` function.  If you just take the first word and capitalize both, does that work?  Do you ignore lines where the date doesn't match?

Comment: @TimRoberts It is for work I am trying to learn Python for it and the name is a free text field from the data so  Preferred  names are incorporated so I am trying to find a better way to match on.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to help you formulate a rule.  The machine will NEVER be able to match "Bob" and "Robert", for example, but the rule I described works fine for the dataset you have above.

Comment: I get what you are saying and thank you for helping and yeah in this example you're rule would help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a possible combination of a "fuzzy merge" and a "nearest date merge".

There are many posts already on those topics but perhaps this specific example is useful:

- [rapidfuzz](/questions/tagged/rapidfuzz)'s [`.cdist()`](https://maxbachmann.github.io/RapidFuzz/Usage/process.html) for fast fuzzy matching
- [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) for the date merge

```
import rapidfuzz

scores = rapidfuzz.process.cdist(
   df2['Name'], df1['NAME'], workers=-1, scorer=rapidfuzz.distance.JaroWinkler.similarity
)

# pick closest match (max score)
NAME = df1['NAME'].loc[scores.argmax(axis=1)].set_axis(df2.index)
# discard non-matches
NAME = NAME[scores.max(axis=1) > 0]

# merge_asof requires sorted keys
pd.merge_asof(
   df2.assign(NAME=NAME).sort_values('Start_Date'),
   df1.sort_values('PRIOR_DATE'),
   by='NAME',
   left_on='Start_Date',
   right_on='PRIOR_DATE',
)
```

```
       ID     Name Start_Date   End_Date     Team      NAME  REQUEST_ID CREATED_DATE PRIOR_DATE    STATUS
0   10002    Grace 2021-07-24 2021-12-31  Finance     GRACE         NaN          NaT        NaT       NaN
1   10001     Adam 2021-09-24 2021-12-22     Tech      ADAM         NaN          NaT        NaT       NaN
2   10025    Blake 2021-11-22 2022-03-12    Sales  BLAKE D.         NaN          NaT        NaT       NaN
3   10000  Michael 2021-11-23 2022-01-23    Sales       NaN         NaN          NaT        NaT       NaN
4   10001     Adam 2021-12-22 2022-04-05       HR      ADAM       100.0   2022-01-24 2021-10-24  Approved  # <- not valid
5   10002    Grace 2021-12-31 2022-03-05  Finance     GRACE         NaN          NaT        NaT       NaN
6   10000  Michael 2022-01-23 2022-05-02    Sales       NaN         NaN          NaT        NaT       NaN
7   10002    Grace 2022-03-05 2022-09-23     Tech     GRACE       101.0   2022-04-12 2022-01-12  Approved
8   10025    Blake 2022-03-12 2022-06-30    Sales  BLAKE D.         NaN          NaT        NaT       NaN
9   10001     Adam 2022-04-05 2022-09-21       HR      ADAM       100.0   2022-01-24 2021-10-24  Approved
10  10025    Blake 2022-06-30 2022-09-12    Sales  BLAKE D.       102.0   2022-09-21 2022-06-21   Pending
```

The asof merge doesn't apply the range check, e.g. row `4` here needs to be "set to NaN".

e.g.

```
df.loc[
   ~df['Start_Date'].between(df['PRIOR_DATE'], df['CREATED_DATE']), 
   'STATUS'
] = float('nan')
```

---

As `Michael` has no match in `df1` it ends up being matched to `ADAM` with a score of `0`.

```
0         ADAM
1         ADAM
2         ADAM
3         ADAM
4         ADAM
5        GRACE
6        GRACE
7        GRACE
8     BLAKE D.
9     BLAKE D.
10    BLAKE D.
Name: NAME, dtype: object
```

Which is why we have the `> 0` filter:

```
2         ADAM
3         ADAM
4         ADAM
5        GRACE
6        GRACE
7        GRACE
8     BLAKE D.
9     BLAKE D.
10    BLAKE D.
```